# Screen orientation and rotation's odd behavior (landscape is not 1024, 748)?

Tags: ios, orientation

I am using Autolayout.

Ok, I wrote in the code:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        DLog(@"rotated from landscape to portrait")
        DLog(@"self.view.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));

    }
    else if (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        DLog(@"rotated from portrait to landscape")
        DLog(@"self.view.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));

    }
}
```

with the result of:

```
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:] | rotated from portrait to landscape
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:] | self.view.frame: {{0, 0}, {748, 1024}}
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:] | rotated from landscape to portrait
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:] | self.view.frame: {{0, 20}, {768, 1004}}
```

Why is the frame not changing? Why is it not changing to ((0, 0), (1024, 748)) in landscape!?

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots?

Comment: Try looking at the bounds instead of the frame. I'm not sure why frame doesn't work, but bounds does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing the frame, which is the size in the *superview's coordinate system* with the bounds, which are the dimensions within the current view's coordinate system. The superview's coordinate system doesn't change, but the offset may (which is why you see the consistent alteration of the `Y` origin based on the rotation which corresponds to the status bar)

If you replace the references of `view.frame` with `view.bounds` you should see the sizes that you expect. Having replaced the display choice, we see:

```
2013-04-28 11:06:48.208 Autorotation[24308:c07] rotated from portrait to landscape
2013-04-28 11:06:48.209 Autorotation[24308:c07] self.view.bounds: {{0, 0}, {1024, 748}}
2013-04-28 11:06:49.351 Autorotation[24308:c07] rotated from landscape to portrait
2013-04-28 11:06:49.352 Autorotation[24308:c07] self.view.bounds: {{0, 0}, {768, 1004}}
2013-04-28 11:06:50.343 Autorotation[24308:c07] rotated from portrait to landscape
2013-04-28 11:06:50.343 Autorotation[24308:c07] self.view.bounds: {{0, 0}, {1024, 748}}
2013-04-28 11:06:52.173 Autorotation[24308:c07] rotated from landscape to portrait
2013-04-28 11:06:52.174 Autorotation[24308:c07] self.view.bounds: {{0, 0}, {768, 1004}}
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. For some reason, I have trouble understanding the difference between frame and bounds. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the status bar at the top of the screen. It's 20pts.

Since you're using auto layout, it is auto-layouting your view to fit it inside the part of the screen not covered by the status bar.

Comment: I don't think that was his question. Isn't he asking about why the view is not changing its dimensions to fill a landscape screen?

Comment: Yep, I know the status bar takes 20pts of the screen size. I was confused why in portrait the height wasn't 748 (768 - 20 for status bar).